# How do I render 2 different components in 2 different router-outlets using the same angular route?

Tags: angular

I have 2 views, one for representatives and one for admins, the admin route needs to render the dashboard in the main section as well as the admin sidebar in the sidebar section when the /admin route is activated, I've looked at a few youtube videos and documentation for named routes on angular, no dice.
here is a simpified version of the code

APP-ROUTING MODULE

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
        component: AdminDashComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
        component: AdminSidebarComponent,
        outlet: 'sidebar'
    }
];
```

TEMPLATE

```html
<app-banner
    [userIconSwitch]="auth.loggedIn"
    (userIconEvent)="userIconClicked()"
    (menuClicked)="bannerMenuClicked()">
    Datrix 2.0
</app-banner>
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6R6pcMm/MRG-Updated-Logo.jpg" alt=""/>
        <br />
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**EDIT**

The unnamed route is working while the named route is not.

There are no errors in the console.

Comment: is there any error in the console, or what happens? and how do you route to admin?

Comment: I don't fully understand, why not to render both components,  something like `<comp-a></comp-a> <comp-b></comp-b>`

Comment: because the admin route is for the admin, there will be another route that is /rep and it should build the rep componenets

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: how do you route to the admin component, wheres the router link or the router service

Comment: I might be missing something, it was my understanding that you only had to define the route in the app routing module, then navigate to the route, in this case it is: http://localhost:4200/admin

Comment: @RaphaelCastro In the template just one `<router-outlet>` tag. Routing don't have any clue whith one is to with component.

Comment: okay, how do I load 2 different components in 2 different places

Comment: @RaphaelCastro Just nest it inside. You no need to use routing to do this. I will wrote an answear.

Comment: @Mises its possible, check my answer

Comment: @C_Ogoo I don't know are it will be ok. Never work with `outlet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To route directly to both `router-outlets` your url should be like this:

http://localhost:4200/admin(sidebar:admin)

If you are routing via a `routerLink` attribute:

```html
<a 
  [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['admin'], sidebar: ['admin'] } }]">
  Navigate to admin on both outlets
</a>
```

Demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-how-do-i-render-2-different-components-in-2-different-locati)

You can find more on secondary route navigation in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-route-navigation-merging-routes-during-navigation)

> The interesting part of the URL follows the ...:
>
> - The admin is the primary navigation.
> - Parentheses surround the secondary route.
> - The secondary route consists of an outlet name (sidebar), a colon searator, and the secondary route path (admin).

Comment: Ha thats the same way i felt when i got it working .. Epic

Comment: out of curiosity how did you come up with the answer?

Comment: I knew it was possible, so started off with creating a named route and routing to it .. then noticed the difference in the url